# How to create model for anova with mixed effects in r

Tags: r, categorical-data, dataset

I am very new to r. I was wondering what I should look into to perform an ANOVA random effects. I have some data that have different treatment groups, and an observed behavioral rates as a dependent variable. Each observation occurs at a particular spatial bin (e.g. bin 1 would represent 0-2mm away from a stimulus treatment while spatial bin 10 would be 18-20mm away)

I am attempting to pool the observations for each treatment and determine if there is a significant difference between the observations at each spatial bin. I want to account for the assay number within each treatment as a possible random effect, and avoid possible pseudo-replication of each measured observation. Additionally, I wanted to determine if there was a linear relationship between the observed rate of behavior with spatial bin.

I was originally using an ANCOVA to look for differences however that no longer seems appropriate.  Please let me know what functions/packages I would need to look into. I was looking into using lme4 or something like it to build this model and wanted some feedback on this approach. Any suggestions on a better method for approaching this question would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like primarily a software question, and so is probably off-topic for this site.  You can ask programming questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Although someone may want to weigh in on the statistical / modeling questions in your post.

*lme4* is probably the premier package for building mixed effects models.  Along with it you may want to use *lmerTest* package, and the *emmeans* package.

*nlme* is also a very popular package.  With it, you may want to use *car::Anova*, although some claim [it is better to use anova with nested models](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_appropriate_test_for_LMEs). You also want to investigate the *emmeans* package for lme models.

I don't have a favorite between these two packages.  *lme4* is better if you have crossed random effects.  *nlme* allows you to put in correlation structures, which is helpful in some repeated measures designs.

For a few simple examples, see [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_03.html), [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_07.html), and [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_09.html).  (Caveat: these are my own webpages.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had looked into some of these packages already so its nice to know I was in the right direction. I will be looking at those examples later!